# I tried to give a name for a function. There is a result with object not found due to an assignment error

Tags: r, variable-assignment

I have a problem that there is a function (ex:ROC()). I want to assign this function a name such as right_roc <- ROC() but I have an error like that: object 'right_roc' not found. How to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do it without the parenthesis to get the function itself but not the call of the function:

```
# create an alias for the sum function
f <- sum
f(1,2,3)
#[1] 6
```

Do partial function evaluation to create more specific versions of a function:

```
right_roc <- purrr::partial(nsROC::gROC, side="right")
right_roc(X, D)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. For f, it is ok :) However, I want to use the function (similar to ROC()) which is more specific. This function has the side part, biomarker and diagnosis part.  I run it you said, the result on console: could not find function "right_roc" :(

Comment: Do you want not just aliasing, but partial evaluation? https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/partial.html From which package does your `ROC` function come from?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks a lot danlooo. Actually, I want to use gROC() function coming from nsROC package. I write in this way: right_roc <- gROC(X, D, side="right"). Here, X:Biomarker value and D:Diagnosis(0:healthy, 1:patient), side is right because I want right-sided ROC curve. Again, I write "right_roc" and run it. object "right_roc" not found and exists("right_roc") is F. Where is the problem you think?

Comment: @ella I revised my answer

Comment: You are perfect! It runs finally, danke schön :) Have a nice day and best regards...